# "java decompiler" JD-Core 0.6.0 / JD-GUI 0.3.3 decompiled code meaning

Tags: java, decompiler

```
 MohrAboutBox.1 local1 = new ActionListener() {
```

I decompiled a jar file with JD GUI 0.3.3 and I got this line which make no sense to me. The ".1" (dot one), what is it referencing to? I tried to recompile and I had an error from javac compiler, it says that it is not a statement that line. What should I do ? I suppose I have to remove ".1" or put "this" instead, or some variable, class or method, I have no idea why the JD cannot do that job.

```
class MohrAboutBox extends JDialog
{
  public MohrAboutBox(MohrControls paramMohrControls)
  {

    MohrAboutBox.1 local1 = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent paramActionEvent) {
        MohrAboutBox.this.exit_dlg();
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It refers to the fact that this is an instance of the enclosed (anonymous) class (implementing  `ActionListener`) within `MohrAboutBox`, e.g. `MohrAboutBox $1`, change it to:

```
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent paramActionEvent) {
        MohrAboutBox.this.exit_dlg();
    }
};
```

Comment: You are the Guru! This is solved. (despite now I got 80 new other errors but I hope them to be less cryptic than this one)

Answer (score 2):

It was an *anonymous inner class* in the original source; a class without a valid Java name. The Java compiler names the resulting class files `ClassName$1`, `ClassName$2`. It's unclear why the decompiler can't work this out on its own. You'll need to supply the name of the real class from which the inner class is extended -- i.e., `ActionListener`, in this case -- and then the code should compile fine.